# angularjs directive: data binding not working using replaceWith()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am new to angularjs.....I am trying to write a directive which adds some html before and after an element...html is as desired but data binding not happening ... please help

[plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/rAv2Za?p=preview)

```
 my precompile function is as follows



 var linkFunction = function(scope,element,attrs){

        element.removeAttr("cs-options"); 
        var html = getHTML(element);
        element.replaceWith(html);
        $compile(element.parent())(scope);

      }
```

Comment: can you please add full directive function, just to make sure you already inject the `$compile` on your directive.

Comment: please check the plunker link.....i have injected $compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data binding does not work because the `getHTML()` method not copying `{{abc}}` along with the element. You need to update the `link` method as:

```
  var linkFunction = function(scope,element,attrs){
    // do not miss {{abc}}
    var $parent = element.parent();
    element.removeAttr("cs-options"); 
    var html = getHTML($parent);

    // override the parent not the element otherwise 
    // there will be two instances of {{abc}}
    $parent.html(html);

    $compile($parent)(scope);        
  }
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/mckBVu1HfT4fp90Twvum

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way simpler solution, I'm using transclude to have the contents of the element copied into the template.

```
app.directive('csOptions',["$compile",function($compile){
  return{
    restrict:'A',
    transclude:true,
    template:"<form><div ng-transclude></div></form>"
  }
}])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/fqHr6i